# Split a column of values delimited by a space into separate columns for each value in python

Tags: python, pandas, split, data-cleaning

How can I convert the dataset

```
a    |    a b c d 
s    |    e f g h
f    |    i j k l
```

to

```
a | a | b | c | d
s | e | f | g | h
f | i | j | k | l
```

Comment: How is the dataset represented in memory? Is it an array?

Comment: represented as a string

Comment: so, essentially like this?
`dataset = 'a    |    a b c d \
           s    |    e f g h \
           f    |    i j k l'`

Comment: a is an int. a, b, c, d are also integers but the final value of the second column is a string.
i.e.
5    |   120 154 564 5454

Comment: Are these all one column? Does the | represent different columns, do you want the result to be a string, or separate columns?

Comment: no. ' | ' is to separate the two columns.
first column contains integers. and second column contains string. But, the string is special. It is made out of 100 integers which are separated by a space. i.e. '21 215 565 989 989 ... '.
I want all the integers to have separate columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler way is using `expand=True` argument.

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','c'], 'c2':['a b c d','e f g h','i j k l']})

# transform into multiple columns
df = pd.concat([df['c1'],df['c2'].str.split(' ', expand=True)], axis=1)

print(df)

  c1  0  1  2  3
0  a  a  b  c  d
1  b  e  f  g  h
2  c  i  j  k  l
```

Answer (score 4):

Using @chrisz setup

```
df.set_index('col1')['col2'].str.extractall('(\w+)')[0].unstack()
```

Output:

```
match  0  1  2  3
col1             
a      a  b  c  d
f      i  j  k  l
s      e  f  g  h
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data really looks like this:

```
  col1     col2
0    a  a b c d
1    s  e f g h
2    f  i j k l
```

**`join`** with **`findall`**

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.col2.str.findall(r'\w+').values.tolist())).drop('col2', 1)

  col1  0  1  2  3
0    a  a  b  c  d
1    s  e  f  g  h
2    f  i  j  k  l
```

Comment: Niiiiice. Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!

Comment: @Kalpit looking at some of the other answers that have been posted, they may be more efficient, so you might want to choose one of them to use,

Answer (score 2):

Consider this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2], 'col2': ['10 20 30 40', '56 76 554 3243']})

    col1    col2
0   1       10 20 30 40
1   2       56 76 554 3243
```

You can split the integers on col2 using str.split. You can either manually assign the resulting columns or use range as follows. I used the example with range as you mentioned in the comment that you are looking at 99ish columns in all.

```
cols = np.arange(df.col2.str.split(expand = True).shape[1])
df[cols] = df.col2.str.split(expand = True)
```

You get

```
    col1    col2            0   1   2   3
0   1       10 20 30 40     10  20  30  40
1   2       56 76 554 3243  56  76  554 3243
```

Answer (score 2):

### Most compact

```
df.drop('c2', 1).join(df.c2.str.split(expand=True))

  c1  0  1  2  3
0  a  a  b  c  d
1  b  e  f  g  h
2  c  i  j  k  l
```

---

### Disregarding existing columns 1

```
pd.DataFrame([[a] + b.split() for a, b in df.values])

   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  a  b  c  d
1  b  e  f  g  h
2  c  i  j  k  l
```

---

## Disregarding existing columns 2

```
pd.DataFrame([' '.join(r).split() for r in df.values])

   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  a  b  c  d
1  b  e  f  g  h
2  c  i  j  k  l
```

Answer (score 0):

If each row on that dataset is delimited by a new line character, you can do something like this:

```
dataset = '''
a    |    a b c d 
s    |    e f g h
f    |    i j k l
'''
for row in dataset.splitlines():
    print('{} {} {} | {} | {} | {}'.format(*row.split()))
```

And the result will be what you expected.

```
a | a | b | c | d
s | e | f | g | h
f | i | j | k | l
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is in the form of a string, we can do

```
import re
s = "a    |    a b c d"
s = re.sub("\s+[^a-z]"," ",s) # Replacing all non-alphabet characters with a single space
s = re.sub(" ","|",s)
```

This should give you the desired output. Since [pandas' replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) is made on top of standard python re.sub this information should work well for you.