# How to split a column into 4 columns based on spaces in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen similar questions, but it seems all would not work in Python 3.8. I have a dataframe like

```
index id
0   0001 01 12537.30 0
1   0001 01 1278.50 1
2   0001 03 53.10 0
```

where id column should be split into 4 columns, but they are in one column now. I need to split it based on space.

I have tried

```
df2 = df1['id'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(' ')))
```

or

```
df1[["City", "State", "Country",'indicator']] = df1["id"].str.split(pat=" ", expand=True)
```

All told me that
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable.
Does anyone have any idea? Thanks

Comment: I understand excel can do this easily. Is there any way to implement it in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through the hassle of splitting the column, the easy path for you would be to create a new Dataframe with `read_csv` method where the `sep`  argument as spaces or tab (whatever you have there) and `skiprows` argument as 1 and names=[co1, col2, col3,...].

Here is an example to further clarify the above point:

```
new_df = pd.read_csv(path_to_your_file, sep='\\t', skiprows=1, names=['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late, but this is what you can do:

```
df['id'].str.extractall('(\w+)')[0].unstack()
```

Here is the link to the original answer ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473148/13202252)